# heat map of cost function of deep learning algorithm

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, heatmap

I got a csv file which contains the results of the activation function: the problem is that we used a sliding window to detect the object with an increment step = 4.
I want to build the heat map I used a simple function but I didn't get any result

Comment: Please paste a sample of your CSV file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: this is a link to download the file : https://we.tl*****/t-r8fP65O9BQ  Please remove the **** from the url